# $\tilde{H}^n(X,\mathbb{Z})\cong {H}^n(X,\mathbb{Z})\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a differentiable manifold. Consider the homomorphism: $\phi: H^n(X,\mathbb{Z})\to H^n(X,\mathbb{R})$ induced by the inclusion of the constant sheaves $\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{R}$. Let $\tilde{H}^n(X,\mathbb{Z})$ denote the image of ${H}^n(X,\mathbb{Z})$ in $H^n(X,\mathbb{R})$.

My question is: how to show $\tilde{H}^n(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is integral cohomology modulo torsion?

Comment: Universal coefficient theorem for cohomology?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown why are they related

Comment: I don't understand the question: the left side is a free abelian group while the right side is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. Why should they be isomorphic (except in the special case when they're both zero)?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri they are modules

Comment: @Danny Let me say it differently: the left side is countable (if it's finitely generated) while the right side is not. So how can they possibly be isomorphic?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri You are right, Well's book said, it's the integral cohomology modulo torsion.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment by @LordSharktheUnknown, the universal coefficient theorem (applied to both $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb R$) implies that $\tilde H^k(M,\mathbb Z)$ coincides with the image of $Hom_{\mathbb Z}(H_k(M,\mathbb Z),\mathbb Z)$ in $Hom_{\mathbb Z}(H_k(M,\mathbb Z),\mathbb R)$ under the map induced by the inclusion of $\mathbb Z$ into $\mathbb R$. Now any homomorphism from an abelian group to $\mathbb R$ vanishes on the torsion subgroup. Restricting to the free part, you get the inclusion of $\mathbb Z^A$ into $\mathbb R^A$, where $A$ is a set of generators of the free part. So the image is a lattice in the vector space $H^k(M,\mathbb R)$ (but certainly not a linear subspace). In many cases of interest, $H^*(M,\mathbb R)$ is finite dimensional, then this is just like as specific embedding of $\mathbb Z^N$ into $\mathbb R^N$.

Comment: Sorry, the universal coefficient theorem of cohomology says differently, the tensor case is for universal coefficient theorem of homology.

Comment: @Danny: sorry for the error, I have edited the reply.

Comment: Thank you, I agree with your proof, but can you give a rigorous proof to show  H̃ k(M,ℤ) coincides with the image of $Hom_ℤ(H_k(M,ℤ),ℤ)$ in $Hom_ℤ(H_k(M,ℤ),ℝ)$ under the map induced by the inclusion of $ℤ$ into $R$?

Comment: You have to use the naturality part in the universal coefficient theorem to get a commutative diagram of exact sequences induced by the inclusion of $\mathbb Z$ into $\mathbb R$. In the sequence for $\mathbb R$, the EXt group vanishes by general results, and together with commutativity of the diagram, this implies the claim.

Comment: I can't google out the "naturality part in the universal coefficient theorem " and for your proof, where does the Ext of $\mathbb{Z}$ go?

Comment: Suppose that you have a homomorphism $\phi:G_1\to G_2$ between two coefficient groups. Then the theorem gives you an exact sequence for each of the groups. For each term in this sequence, $\phi$ induces a homorphism between the terms in the two sequences and naturality says that these fit together to form a commutative diagram. Commutativity then tells you that the Ext term of $\mathbb Z$ goes to zero. This sounds like an advanced topic for using google, maybe a book on algebraic topology would be more helpful.

Comment: There is a problem in your proof, I think you assumed $H_k(M,Z)$ is in the form of $Z^m\oplus_n Z/n$, however by Moore space, $H_k(M,Z)$ can be Q/Z, which we can not represent in that form.

Comment: I was mainly thinking about the case that homology groups are finitely generated. In any case the line of argument I was sketching should work in general, but I am not sure what the result looks like.

Comment: But the $Ext(H_{n-1}(X),Z)$ is not trivial, even its image in $Hom_Z(H_k(M,Z),R)$ is trivial, but it's still possible that $Ext(H_{n-1}(X),Z)$ is not torsion, if so, then the image  H̃ n(X,ℤ) is not integral cohomology modulo torsion